# With YouTubeApi, How To Have Status Popup When Start Time Changes

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the YouTube API to have buttons under my video change the start time based on some preassigned text.  When I call the `player.seekTo` method, it works exactly as I expect but it's not obvious to the user something changed. I'd like the YouTube status that shows the current time in the video to pop up just like when you change the time by click the time bar on the video.

Here is the code I'm using as well as the page that it works on to help make it clear what I'm talking about.

https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Session/2017/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-git-but-were-afraid-to-ask/Video

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    let player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new window.YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onSetStartTime(startTimeInSeconds) {
        //console.log(startTimeInSeconds);
        player.seekTo(startTimeInSeconds);

    }
```

YouTube API:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls